# Can Identity Server Itself be a client to call a secured api

Tags: identityserver3

When a user logs into identity server I want to call an existing secured API to retrieve some personal data to add into the users claims.

This would mean that identity server would be need to be configured as client using client credential flow and would have to sign into itself at start up.

Is this a supported configuration or should I be looking for an alternate approach?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes you can , have a look at this [sample](https://github.com/IdentityServer/IdentityServer3.Samples/tree/master/source/MVC%20Authentication), which is what I am using in my company, in the `Startup.cs`, it registers both identityserver3 middleware as well as `UseOpenIdConnectAuthentication`.